# Netbeans Java jList losses SelectionMode

Tags: java, netbeans, jlist

I implement a JList that is populated from a Database.
I want to **Multiple Select** from that jList and **Delete** them.

When i select some items and press the DELETE Button the following code is running:

```
    DatabasesConnections m = new DatabasesConnections();
    mFavoriteList = m.deleteFavorite(jList1.getSelectedValue());

    jList1.removeAll();
    DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    mFavoriteList.forEach((favorite) -> {
        listModel.addElement(favorite.getName());
    });

    jList1.setModel(listModel);
```

where m.deleteFavorite method is the following:

```
public List<FavoriteList> deleteFavorite(String name) {
    try {
        if (!em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
        }
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT ID FROM FAVORITE_LIST WHERE NAME= '"+name+"'");

        List results = query.getResultList();
        FavoriteList fl = em.find(FavoriteList.class, results.get(0));
        em.remove(fl);
        em.getTransaction().commit(); 

        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM FavoriteList f");
        List<FavoriteList> mFavorites = q.getResultList();
        return mFavorites;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Check database connection.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you see after the Deletion of the item i return a new List.
Then i set the new Model to the jList1.

**After that the jList is greyed out and i can not MultiSelect as before..**

At first run i can select Multiple:
[image]

After first DELETE i get this jList with no option to Multiple selection:
[image]

Comment: After DELETE, it appears all items are selected, but the call to setModel(listModel) is supposed to clear the selection.  Try calling jList1.clearSelection() after you call jList1.setModel(listModel)